# jQuery width change detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window-resize

**Now Solved, thanks**

I have see a lot of near answers to my problem with resize(), here is my code:

'larger()' is a layout function that I want to call when screen width regardless of device orientation is >= 501, 'smaller()' is a function that i want to call when the screen width is < 501.

**My problem I have is that** I don't want these functions to be called when the window.height changes.  Note that in my page I am using an accordion in mobile view and if I expand an accordion panel, it adds height to the page, even though the browser window hasn't been re-sized.  jQuery sees this as a window.resize.

```
$(window).resize(function(e) {
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    if (winWidth >= 501){
       larger();
    }
    if (winWidth < 501){
       smaller();
    }
});
```

any answers appreciated, and let me know if I need to clarify anything.

I am using `jquery-1.11.0.min.js` with `jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js`

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

How about storing a reference to the previous width and if the width has changed on resize then call your functions - otherwise skip it. Like So:

```
// If you don't want it to change the first time
// then set this value on document load to get initial window width
var prevWinWidth = 0;

$(window).resize(function(e) {
    var winWidth = $(window).width();

    if(winWidth != prevWinWidth) {
        if (winWidth >= 501){
            larger();
        }
        if (winWidth < 501){
            smaller();
        }
        prevWinWidth = winWidth;
    }
});
```

Comment: hi the problem is that I don't want the nested functions to get called on height change, when page height changes.  I guess what I need is a way to detect the physical browser re-size, not the window

Comment: But they won't get called if there is a height change without a width change. If you never want the functions to be called if the height has changed then use a variable to track also the height change and only call your functions when the width has changed but the height hasn't

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable that keeps track of the last known width of the window. Only if the width is changing, evaluate the width to call the appropriate function.

```
var lastWidth = 0;
$(window).resize(function (e) {
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    if (lastWidth !== winWidth) {
        winWidth >= 501 ? larger() : smaller();
        lastWidth = winWidth;
    }
});
```